# How can I get Visual Studio Code autosave working again?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosave

The Visual Studio Code setting `"files.autoSave": "onWindowChange"` has stopped working for me. It has worked properly for me every day in the past year. (I'm wondering if it may possibly be related to either my most recent update to Catalina or the most recent update to VS Code.) I have the files.autoSave setting only in this file: ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can get the autosave feature in vscode working again?

Visual Studio Code 1.49.0
Commit: e790b931385d72cf5669fcefc51cdf65990efa5d
Date: 2020-09-10T17:39:53.251Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0 - macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Answer (score 1):

i personally don't like to use autosave  on window change. I use "files.autoSave": "afterDelay" and set the delay files.autoSaveDelay": 500 here. Why I used this over the autosave window change is because it's much faster and automatically done every 500ms!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like it. I tried it but this is not working either.

Comment: what? why is it not working? can you screenshoot me your settings.json file

Answer (score 0):

I was using Witch by Many Tricks, https://manytricks.com/witch/. After updating MacOs to Catalina 10.15.6, I believe that Which may have been interfering with VS Code ability receive window focus callbacks (I'm guessing). When I disabled Which, all is fine now. Thank you.